# Creating Observation in Data.frame based on specific vector

Tags: r

so in my case i have  a data.frame which looks like follows.

```
date <- c("13.02","12.02","10.01")
text <- c("textabc")
time <- c("10 o'clock")
```

In the end my data.frame should like this:

[image]

So for every date string there should be a new observation in the data.frame.
How can i do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cbind.fill()` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
names <- c("text", "date", "time")
df <- cbind.fill(text, date, time)
colnames(df) <- names
# df output
     text  date       time
1 textabc 13.02 10 o'clock
2 textabc 12.02 10 o'clock
3 textabc 10.01 10 o'clock
```